# Cognito Access Token "cognito:groups" missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I want to authenticate my API Gateway requests with Cognito.

For that i created custom scopes. API Gateway checks those scopes and proxies these requests to my Elastic Beanstalk API. This works fine.

But another part of my Authorization are groups. Based on a assigned group some actions have restricted Access. I need to use groups because i want to be able to add or remove those groups during user-lifecycle. The group will be checked in my Elastic Beanstalk API.

---

**Problem**
The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-access-token) states that Access Tokens contain the `cognito:groups` claim. But a setup like in the Image below **does not include** this claim in my token.[image]

The following decoded jwt will be produced after a login via hosted-UI. As you can see the claim is missing. ID tokens (with `openid` scope) will include this group. I am also sure that i've tested Cognito earlier with Amplify JS-SDK which included the group. But there i was unable to include my custom scopes.

```json
{
  "sub": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "token_use": "access",
  "scope": "api.example.com/item.read api.example.com/item.write",
  "auth_time": 1615325374,
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_xxxxxxx",
  "exp": 1615328974,
  "iat": 1615325374,
  "version": 2,
  "jti": "f37219a5-c8b0-411b-bdb3-ab7d9201b491",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "username": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Do I miss about a restriction or configuration issue? Why is the group missing inside my Access Tokens?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I haven't tested it but I think you are missing the `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` scope. It's needed to deal with user account's data. And since groups are part of user's account I assume it should work after you add it.

Comment: unfortunately this does not change anything. Also if I only choose `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` I can´t see the group-claim. Is the use of Cognito Hosted UI a problem? I'd rather use Amplify SDK in Javascript. But there I'am unable to include the custom scopes.

Comment: I just noticed you don't have the `openid` scope. I would give it a try.

Comment: Yeah but this will transform the access token to an identity token. this not what i intended

Comment: There are always 3 tokens. Access, Id and Refresh.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit further? If i include `openid` the Token becomes an identity Token (`token_use : id`). With this variant the scopes are missing.

Comment: All I'm trying to say, is that authentication in Cognito should always return 3 tokens: an `IdToken`, an `AccessToken` and a `RefreshToken`. Not sure about your exact architecture, but all tokens should always be available to you.

Comment: The client (with amplify-sdk) may have those three. But the API Gateway only receives the `AccessToken`. So I don't (and I shouldn't) have all three Tokens available when Authentication/Authorization occurs in API-Gateway

Comment: It seems Cognito returns only two tokens (access and refresh) unless you specify `openid` scope, in which case it returns all three AND the returned access token contains `cognito:group` claim. This appears to be some kind of data protection measure, because user groups belong to user identity and if the client app isn't allowed to get the id token, it means it cannot get any information about the user identity.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. The cognito:groups value appeared after I added the openid scope:

[image: Screenshot of app client settings]

and the access token is still supplied, as per earlier comments.

Comment: As per the comment above, I think this is the right answer. This appears to be some kind of data protection measure, because user groups belong to user identity and if the client app isn't allowed to get the id token, it means they must not be able to get any information about the user identity. I couldn't find it anywhere in AWS Cognito documentation though

Comment: I'm still unable to see it in the ID token or the access token after openid or profile is selected