# Cognito Access Token missing "cognito:groups" claim

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-access-token.html#user-pool-access-token-payload) states that Access Token contains the `cognito:groups` claim.

Other answers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68311699/1302308) suggest adding the `openid` scope, but this scope is already enabled:

[image]

Using **currentAuthenticatedUser**, the `signInUserSession` payload has all 3 tokens (`accessToken`, `idToken`, and `refreshToken`):

[image: signInUserSession payload]

But the accessToken payload is missing `cognito:groups` along with all custom attributes:

```json
auth_time: 1675179728
client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
event_id: "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
exp: 1675183327
iat: 1675179728
iss: "https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_xxxxxxxxxx"
jti: "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
origin_jti: "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
scope: "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
sub: "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
token_use: "access"
username: "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

The idToken has a `cognito:username` but that's the only Cognito related attribute provided.

I have a previous user pool that this one is based off (same Serverless configuration) which does provide the `cognito:groups` attribute. I am migrating to this user pool to allow case insensitivity.

If it's not the `openid` scope, is there something else that I'm missing?

I've made sure that the `openid` scope has been added, tried adding `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` scope, and have compared setting between my working user pool and the one that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, I had an old user pool that provided the cognito:groups attribute, but after creating a new user pool it was missing the cognito:groups attribute.

Please make sure to check openid, aws.cognito.signin.user.admin two options
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UabLf.png)

I originally updated the settings and continued to use the old Token and still can’t get the cognito:groups attribute, but if you get a new Cognito Token to access your endpoint, you will get the cognito:groups attribute.